# What happened when I use a host volume(bind mounts) and named volume(one type of docker managed volume) at the same time?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, mount-point

I have read the some documents before asking this question:

- https://docs.docker.com/glossary/?term=volume
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

And I am confused about the following two parts:

1. bind mounts: [Mounting into a non-empty directory on the container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mounting-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container)
2. named volume: [Populate a volume using a container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container)

Their behavior is completely opposite:

For bind mounts:

> If you bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount.

For named volume and anonymous volumes:

> If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume. The container then mounts and uses the volume, and other containers which use the volume also have access to the pre-populated content.

My question is, if I use a `VOLUME` command in dockerfile to create a <del>named volume</del> anonymous volumes, and at the same time, use a bind mount to mount a non exist path into the container, what goes on behind the scenes?

For example:

```
# in docker file
VOLUME /path/in/container

# when run container
docker run -v /not-exist-dir/in/host:/path/in/container  ... /< image >
```

I have do some test and the result is:

1. no anonymous volumes was created in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`
2. the not-exist-dir was created on the host and it is not empty now, I think the [Populate a volume using a container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) has take effects.

So,

1. why there is no anonymous volumes created as expected?
2. why the directory’s existing contents(in container side) are not obscured by the bind mount?

what happened behind this scenario?

---

Let me give a more specific example:

Here is the [dockerfile of the openfrontier/gerrit image](https://hub.docker.com/r/openfrontier/gerrit/dockerfile), we can see at the end of the docker file, there is a VOLUME command:

```
VOLUME $GERRIT_SITE
```

which will actually create an anonymous volumes on the host and mount it to `/var/gerrit/review_site`(value of GERRIT_SITE) in the container when any container is created from this image like this:

```
docker run -dit --name gerrit  openfrontier/gerrit:2.15.3
```

after that, I can see the anonymous volumes under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` and I can use `docker volume ls` to see its name `be4538dbf3a51da463391c6eca9714fb6dd0c11379f1e2918f74c33d56633f00`, and also with `docker inspect gerrit` command, we can see:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "be4538dbf3a51da463391c6eca9714fb6dd0c11379f1e2918f74c33d56633f00",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/be4538dbf3a51da463391c6eca9714fb6dd0c11379f1e2918f74c33d56633f00/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/gerrit/review_site",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
```

and there are some file under these two folder, which are created by the container after it running.

Till now, this is a normal example for create an anonymous volumes by using VOLUME command.

However, if I run this container with the following command:

```
docker run -dit --name gerrit -v /home/test:/var/gerrit/review_site openfrontier/gerrit:2.15.3
```

where `/home/test` is not exist on the host, then no anonymous volumes is created, instead, `/home/test` folder is created and it is not empty!!!, the mount info is as follows:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/test",
                "Destination": "/var/gerrit/review_site",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

I think bind mounts is take effects here but I just do not understand why the path on the host is not empty(since bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount.)

I also test mounting a not empty folder to the container by put some file under "/home/test" before I use `docker run` to start a container, the result is the original file was kept and new files was added too.

I know the examples above are not good practice to use docker volume, But I just wondering what happened behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The volume declaration in the Dockerfile sets a bit of metadata on the image that tells `docker run` to define an anonymous volume at that location any time a container is made from that image. This is not a named volume or host mount, but it has a lot in common with both (they are all bind mounts by default, and anonymous volumes are listed in `docker volume ls` along with named volumes).

However, when you specify a host mount to the same container directory, that takes precedence (two volume mounts to the same directory inside the container will not happen). Any modifications to that directory by the commands running inside the container will be visible on the host, but the directory itself will not be initialized by the image contents.

If you want to initialize a host directory with image contents, you can use a named volume that performs a bind mount. There are a few differences in behaviour from the host mount. Mainly the directory must exist in advance, and inside a compose file you must use absolute paths instead of relative ones. I've got the syntax for that in my presentation here:

https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018eu/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#48

Comment: Thanks very much for your kindly help! I know the example above is not a good practice. Here is my understanding of your answer: when I use anonymous volume and bind mounts at the same time, only bind mounts will take effects, right?

Comment: @ChiuCheng when you define a setting in an image, and a different value for the same setting in a container based on that image, the container setting always takes precedence. So with two volume definitions for the same directory, the value you set during `docker run` or in a compose file will be the one to apply.

Comment: Note that I strongly recommend against volumes defined inside a Dockerfile. They break things in non-intuitive ways. E.g. any attempt to change the directory with a RUN command after the volume is defined will silently fail. And you can end up with lots of anonymous volumes for temporary containers that you never needed to preserve the data. Defining the volume at runtime when you need it is my preference.

Comment: @BMitch I cannot figure out why `docker run -v /home/user/wordpress:/var/www/html  wordpress` would initialize the host directory (/home/user/wordpress) with image content; would you mind shed some light on it?

Comment: @Max the entrypoint in the wordpress image does that, docker doesn't initialize the host folder itself.

Comment: @Dzenly anonymous volumes are automatically deleted when you use `--rm`, try a running container: `docker run --name redis-test --rm -d redis:latest && docker inspect redis-test --format '{{json .Config.Volumes}}'`

Comment: I did not use --rm

Comment: Hmm, seems like I was wrong.
There is 
            "Volumes": {
                "/myvolume": {}
            },
in docker inspect output. And I see some hash in /var/lib/docker/volumes, which contains my files from container.
Interesting that this path does not show in docker inspect output.

Comment: @Dzenly to get your anonymous volume id, look in the Mounts: `docker inspect redis-test --format '{{json .Mounts}}' | jq`

Comment: @BMitch Interesting. Nor .Mounts neither .Config.Mounts do not show anything. Even for named volume. I.e. i see named volume in my /var/lib/docker/volumes, but I can not see it in docker inspect output. %)
`Template parsing error: template: :1:14: executing "" at <.Config.Mounts>: map has no entry for key "Mounts"`

Comment: Oh, I see. I used docker inspect on image. Firstly I running it by docker run and my container name was equal to image name. Then I changed to docker-compose. And container name is changed. Sorry for false alarm and thank you for help.

Comment: @Dzenly You can disambiguate with `docker container inspect`

Answer (score 3):

There are some mixed up things in your question, and since it's not always intuitive, I'll try to make it clearer through example.

*Notes :*

- It's a small tuto I wrote about volumes for my co-workers. There must be some flaws in the explanations, but the exemples have all been tested.
- it's important you run the things in the following order, and not rerun commands (because "new" things mays then become "existing" and would not match their purpose)
- I'll mount to some system path... it's only for exemple purpose : to ensure they exist as well as to avoid multiplying preliminar creation commands.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu

VOLUME /tmp/dockerfilevolumefromnowhere

RUN mkdir -p /dir/created/from/container
RUN touch /dir/created/from/container/emptyFile.txt
VOLUME /dir/created/from/container

CMD "sh"
```

**let's remove all previous tests data**

BE AWARE THAT IT WILL REMOVE ALL VOLUMES THAT ARE NOT USED ANYMORE, including those that you may have created previously.

If you have any running containers (especially if they use volumes), please stop them for the purpose of these tests.

```
root@host:~# docker container prune 
root@host:~# docker volume prune 
root@host:~# rm -r /does/not/exit/within/host
root@host:~# rm -r /does/not/exit/within/host2
root@host:~# rm -r /tmp/dockerfilevolumefromnowhere
```

**some image and volume creations and filling**

```
root@host:~# docker build -t tmpcontainer .
root@host:~# docker volume create existingVolume
root@host:~# touch /var/lib/docker/volumes/existingVolume/_data/someExistingFile.txt
root@host:~# docker volume create existingVolume2
root@host:~# touch /var/lib/docker/volumes/existingVolume2/_data/anotherExistingFile.txt
root@host:~# docker volume create existingEmptyVolume
```

at this time you have 3"existing volumes":

```
root@host:~# docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               existingVolume
local               existingVolume2
local               existingEmptyVolume
```

**Let's now run our container**

```
docker run -it \
-v /does/not/exit/within/host:/does/not/exist/within/container \
-v /does/not/exit/within/host2:/sbin \
-v /tmp:/again/another/does/not/exist/within/container \
-v /tmp:/tmp/ \
-v newVolume:/another/does/not/exist/within/container \
-v newVolume2:/bin \
-v existingVolume:/new/path/on/container \
-v existingVolume2:/usr \
-v existingEmptyVolume:/var \
bash: groups: command not found # that's normal. you overrided the /usr... see beyond
```

Now, we are connected on our newly created container.

**Let's see what we have on both container and host** :

```
# -v /does/not/exit/within/host:/does/not/exist/within/container 
#no one exists on both sides : both directories are created, and are now bound to each other
root@host:~# ll /does/not/exit/within/host
. 
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /does/not/exist/within/container
.

# -v /does/not/exit/within/host:/sbin 
# the directory on host is created, and the one on container is erased with this new one. Both are now bound to each other
root@host:~# ll /does/not/exit/within/host2
. 
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /sbin
.


# -v /tmp:/again/another/does/not/exist/within/container
# the path on host exists, and the path on container will be created and will hold the content on container (they are bound to each other)
root@host:~# ll /tmp
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 one.txt
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 two.yml
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /again/another/does/not/exist/within/container
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 one.txt
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 two.yml

# -v /tmp:/tmp
# the path on host exists, so all its content will replace the previously path on container
# there were some data on container's /tmp, but they are replaced with hosts ones
root@host:~# ll /tmp
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 one.txt
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 two.yml
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /tmp
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 one.txt
    -rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 two.yml

# -v newVolume:/another/does/not/exist/within/container \
# the newVolume does not exist, so it will be created and bound to path on container.  
# since the path on container is new, it will be created empty
root@host:~#  ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/newVolume/_data/
..
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /another/does/not/exist/within/container
..

# -v newVolume2:/bin \
# once again, a volume will be created, but since it matches an existing path on container, it will hold all the content of it (no erasal!)
root@host:~#  ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/newVolume2/_data/
<all the content of Ubuntu's /bin from within container>
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /bin
<whole expected content of /bin on Ubuntu>

# -v existingVolume:/new/path/on/container \
# the volume exists, and it -and all files within- will be bound to a newly created path on container
root@host:~#  ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/existingVolume/_data/
-rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 someExistingFile.txt
 root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /new/path/on/container
-rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 someExistingFile.txt


# -v existingVolume2:/usr \ 
# the volume exists, so does the path on container. It will replace the existing path (and thus erase the former files there) and will be bound to this replaced path.
root@host:~#  ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/existingVolume2/_data/
-rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 anotherExistingFile.txt
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /usr    
-rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 11:11 anotherExistingFile.txt

# -v existingEmptyVolume:/var \ 
# the volume exists, but is empty. the path on container exists in the container and is not empty. In this case, the path on container will not be erased and this will act as a new volume.
root@host:~#  ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/existingEmptyVolume/_data/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 24  2018 backups/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 cache/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 lib/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 Apr 24  2018 local/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov 12 21:54 lock -> /run/lock/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 log/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail  4096 Nov 12 21:54 mail/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 21:54 opt/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     4 Nov 12 21:54 run -> /run/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 spool/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 21:56 tmp/
root@ffb82b56d64b:/# ll /var  
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 24  2018 backups/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 cache/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 lib/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 Apr 24  2018 local/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov 12 21:54 lock -> /run/lock/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 log/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail  4096 Nov 12 21:54 mail/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 21:54 opt/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     4 Nov 12 21:54 run -> /run/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 spool/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 21:56 tmp/
```

Note that now, the previously existing and newly created volume can be used for other containers (the same way you just used previously existing ones here above).

Eventually, all that we have left to cover all our uses cases are the **volumes created from the Dockerfile**.
Let's look at the content of /var/lib/docker/volumes. Remember we have cleaned it before performing our tests, so all those here match our tests.

```
root@host:~# ll /var/lib/docker/volumes
drwx------  6 root root  4096 Feb 19 11:11 ./
drwx--x--x 14 root root  4096 Feb 14 09:50 ../
-rw-------  1 root root 65536 Feb 19 14:36 metadata.db #indeed 
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 635af95ec06f8a44c22915005189bfb12d5bcf2e5ac97c25112d3e65a72546f4/ # anonymous container 1
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 897b28ec17275a3c3be184bb20b6314b38c1404e638080c8fe4fc36cae2f9f65/ # anonymous container 2
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 existingEmptyVolume/ #we created it (empty) before the run command
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:35 existingVolume/ #we created it before the run command
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 existingVolume2/ #we created it before the run command
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 newVolume/ #we created it during run command
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 19 14:36 newVolume2/ #we created it during run command
```

So what are those anonymous containers : they are actually the ones created from you dockerfile.
Let's check their content.

```
root@host:~#  ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/63eeedcb1aa2e4d8785cca409698371381558348ce19bc614d87da372901d224/_data/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 19 10:14 emptyFile.txt
root@host:~#  ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/ea0ed5ff271cba03a8b7d35144b58e8da1b2e50b4e05c4cccda7f19b401d7f0b/_data/
..
```

See, they are holding whatever you put in them from the dockerfile. 
They are anonymous, so you cannot (or actually must not) use them from other containers because new ones will be created for every time you run a container from this image.

*Note* : You may have noticed some odd thing at this time:

```
root@host:~# ll /tmp/dockerfilevolumefromnowhere #YES : from HOST!
.. #it exists... but is not linked to the volume or the path in container in any way.
```

Here... don't ask : it is still puzzling me why it is created on host. I guess it's a bug, but this an issue that should be discussed on docker ML, not here.
Anyway, you are not supposed to do it that way : mkdir before creating the volume over it!

**So what we can see with all these exemples :**

- bind / mounting from hosts **path** to container (/some/path/on/host:/a/path/on/container) will create the path on container (no matter it does exist previously) and replace all former data here. Both directories (and their contents) are now bound to each other.
- mounting from **volume** (someVolumeName:/a/path/on/container) to container , will bind the volume to the path on container.
- mounting an **existing non-empty volume** to a container's path will replace the (possible) content within the container with the content from the existing volume (if empty : it will act as a new volume)
- mounting a **new volume** to a container's path will bind the content of the path in the container with the volume. The volume will now hold this content (eg for later use) : nothing will be erased / replaced here.
- both volume or path (whatever if it's on container or host) will be **created if not existing.**
- **volume from Dockerfile** will be anonymous and re-created everytime you run another container from this image (previous ones will remain). They will created under /var/lib/docker/volumes as well.
- **volume declared at run** command will be created (ie will be "new" volumes) if they did not exist previously. Otherwise, existing ones will be used instead.
- **volume created  through the run command** will be persisted in /var/lib/docker/volumes under a directory matching their name.

*Note :* that I am not talking about ownership and rights here. On purpose: that's another matter we may discuss later.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kindly help! I add a specific example to this question to make it more clear. I know its not good to use the bind mounts and the docker managed volume at the same time, but I just want to konw what actually happened when I do this.

Comment: BMitch gave the right answer : "any attempt to change the directory with a RUN command after the volume is defined will silently fail"

Comment: Marvin, I asked related question about `RUN` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099955/dockerfile-changes-made-to-filesystem-via-run-do-not-persist and got pointer to doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume "Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded." But that only applied to build stage. Why `docker run` (small letters used in OP question) have same effect - can you point me to some docs? Thanx.

Comment: @ChiuCheng, though I just asked for clarifications, I will try to guess the answer to as least your question in the comment above - looks to me that contents were obscured initially at initialisation (docs you quoted: "the directory’s **existing** contents are obscured by the bind mount.") and were created later (your wrote for 1st example: "which are created by the container **after** it running.")