# Dockerfile: changes made to filesystem via RUN do not persist

Tags: docker

I could not find that spoecifics via web search for `site:stackoverflow.com dockerfile RUN fs changes not persisted`.

I made `Dockerfile` and wanted to make some changes in image via `RUN`. Firstly I wanted to change file attributes, but changes were not there in started container. I've found this post taking about `docker` bug for `chmod` and workarounds: https://serverfault.com/questions/772227/chmod-not-working-correctly-in-docker. However, now I just try to create a file via `RUN touch /path/file` in `Dockerfile` and already on next command (next layer for docker as I understood the docs) changes (that file) are gone. As far as I see it is strange, otherwise how `apt install` works then because it will make changes to file system in the image... Why results of that particular `RUN` do not persist? Docs below tell opposite (or I misunderstand meaning of `commit` here):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ :

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of
>   the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed
>   image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

Here is output of `docker build --no-cache -t yandex:user5 yandex2/` (see steps 6 and 7; dockeruser is created, *btw*):

```
Step 1/8 : FROM artifactory.dev.foo.org:5000/yandex-tank:jmeter
 ---> b8286a9220ca
Step 2/8 : LABEL maintainer="foo@foo.org"
 ---> Running in 7cfde9a90bf2
Removing intermediate container 7cfde9a90bf2
 ---> b5acd9d55f9c
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /var/loadteest
 ---> Running in 47e9adc401bb
Removing intermediate container 47e9adc401bb
 ---> 103f158e0be3
Step 4/8 : USER root
 ---> Running in 9923d71f7b08
Removing intermediate container 9923d71f7b08
 ---> bb3aa8672bc6
Step 5/8 : RUN groupadd -r dockeruser &&    useradd -r -g dockeruser -d /var/loadtest -s /sbin/nologin -c "Docker image user" dockeruser
 ---> Running in 48c89f33d750
Removing intermediate container 48c89f33d750
 ---> 5000afa7698d
Step 6/8 : RUN touch /var/loadtest/chmodtest.txt
 ---> Running in 00b2d1ccad75
Removing intermediate container 00b2d1ccad75
 ---> c35808f13344
Step 7/8 : RUN ls -al /var/loadtest
 ---> Running in cc08d129eeb3
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 20 12:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 29 06:15 ..
Removing intermediate container cc08d129eeb3
 ---> 842678ca5d49
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
 ---> Running in 20b92a97c8a8
Removing intermediate container 20b92a97c8a8
 ---> fefd0d665677
Successfully built fefd0d665677
Successfully tagged yandex:user5
```

Comment: did you use any volumes in the dockerfile of `artifactory.dev.foo.org:5000/yandex-tank:jmeter` ?

Comment: @LinPy, not in mine last one (can be seen from output posted), but when I ran `docker history --no-trunc yandex:user5` I see e.g. that line: `VOLUME [/var/loadtest] `

Comment: that is the issue , you can not write to volumes in your dockerfile, see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is using the volumes in the base image:

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps
>   change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those
>   changes will be discarded.

see [This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume)

Comment: I see now. How can I change that folder then? any simple way?

Comment: no it is not posible , you need to change the base image or change your working directory

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is to use `COPY` [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

```
COPY path/to/local/file /var/loadtest/chmodtest.txt
```

Comment: `COPY` in fact changes the contents, but it requires to make any necessary changes _outside_ the image build - so the files must be prepared _before_ docker build runs.